# How to write an if statement using == for data loaded as json loads

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I wrote this code and modified it many times, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

python

```
while True:
    headers = {'client-id': twitch_Client_ID, 'Authorization': authorization}
    response_channel = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=' + twitchID, headers=headers)
    print(response_channel.text)

    try:
        if loads(response_channel.text)['data'][0]['type'] == 'live' and check == False:
            title = loads(response_channel.text)['data'][0]['title']
            game_name = loads(response_channel.text)['data'][0]['game_name']
            username = loads(response_channel.text)['data'][0]['user_name']
            thumbnail = 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_scw1101-1920x1080.jpg'

            twitch_embed = discord.Embed(title=title , description="\n 방송보러가기 : https://www.twitch.tv/scw1101")
            twitch_embed.add_field(name="스트리머", value=username, inline=True)
            twitch_embed.add_field(name="게임 이름", value=game_name, inline=True)
            twitch_embed.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
            await channel.send("<@everyone> 오뱅온~", embeds=twitch_embed)
            print("Online")
            check = True
    except:
        print("Offline")
        check = False

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

json

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "39807966251",
        "user_id": "119609287",
        "user_login": "bboyul",
        "user_name": "뽀율",
        "game_id": "19620578",
        "game_name": "Super People",
        "type": "live",
        "title": "입 딜 은 세 계 최 강 !（︶^︶）ﾉ",
        "viewer_count": 14,
        "started_at": "2021-08-13T13:02:23Z",
        "language": "ko",
        "thumbnail_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_bboyul-{width}x{height}.jpg",
        "tag_ids": ["ab2975e3-b9ca-4b1a-a93e-fb61a5d5c3a4"],
        "is_mature": false
    }],
    "pagination": {}
}
```

I'm making a twitch live notification bot using discord.py. However, it is difficult because there are not many data in Korea. Please help

**Edit**

json response comes, print("offline") works even though data type is live, notification doesn't work

Comment: Don't call `loads(response_channel.text)` repeatedly. Load the JSON into a variable once, then reference that.

Answer (score 0):

Not only loads, use json.loads and save the result.

```
response_json = json.loads(response_channel.text) 
if response_json['data'][0]['type'] == 'live' and check == False:
```

Comment: My understanding is that he was already using `json.loads`, but imported the function from the module and it was omitted

Comment: Yes keep attention to import `import json`

Comment: Please add more information on the error. it is not clear where is the exception, Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).